# DroneDeploy generated Ortho shows skewed in QGIS (projections OK?)

Tags: qgis, orthophoto, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I've recently bought a drone and have been having a lot of fun enhancing maps with very detailed orthomosaics.

The images place correctly once loaded in QGis, absolute positioning is good enough for what I want to do etc.

The images generated should be WGS84, in Qgis, when looking at the properties that is also reflected. I've set the project properties based on the image.

I've got a very nice and square tennis court, when I view it on the DroneDeploy website it shows as a proper square. However, once loaded in QGIS it's pretty badly skewed.

I'm a (Q)GIS newby and rely on Google to learn things.

I've not been able to figure out what is going on past the checking of projections.

Any suggestions, it's a private property so I can't link to the full image. But if an image is useful I can add some partial screenshots

Comment: A screenshot of the layers extent could be helpful, as reported by properties, metadata tab. I doubt that WGS84 is correct, because one degree of latitude is not as long as one degree of öongitude unless you are close to the equator.

Comment: I agree with @AndreJ.
Screenshots would help.
WGS84 will not produce square anything.
The DroneDeploy website is simply going to display a mosaic of square pixels if what I read is correct.
The camera will collect an image of square pixels with a position tag from the onboard GPS if there is one installed, or you will rectify the position of the image with known points on the ground. |

I would reproject the image, and the other data to a Cartesian system (measurement units in feet or meters rather than degrees) to see if you still have the skew.

Comment: I high underestimated how much of an impact the projection would have on the display. I changed to Canada_Lambert_Conformal and things look great. I took a screenshot of WGS84 and Lambert and overlaid them: [Projection Effect](http://bit.ly/2oWY5Ao). Thank you both for the suggestion

Comment: I am glad it helped!
Something to consider.
WGS84 is a datum, not a projection. It is a model of the entire earth, and the model is sort of a ball that is being squeezed at both poles to make the ball less than round. They call that shape an oblate spheroid.
The distance around the equator is greater than the distance around the poles.
What a projection does is lay a flat (rectangular) surface on that misshapen spheroid, and warps it to fit the spheroid. Kind of like taking some plastic wrap drawing a rectangle on it, then placing it on a ball. The rectangle is distorted to fit.